# Exchange Server 2010 & Active Directory

Tags: exchange-server

I have Active Directory on Windows Server 2003 SP1 R2
and
Exchange Server 2010 on Windows Server 2008

Can i joining these servers together, Exchange Server with this Active Directory Domain 
or that will make a problems and what is the better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating Active Directory into your Exchange Infrastructure gives you a considerable options and flexibity because active Directory and Exchange work well together.

As [stated by Jaap Wesselius](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj159096.aspx):

> When you separate a network into multiple physical locations,
>   connected with “slow” links and separated into multiple IP subnets,
>   you create “sites,” in Active Directory terms.Like for example office
>   located in Germany with an IP subnet of 10.10.0.0/16. There might be a
>   branch office located in Bulguria with an IP subnet of 10.11.0.0/16.
>   Both locations have their own Active Directory DC, and handle client
>   authentication in their own subnet. Active Directory site links
>   control replication traffic between sites. Clients in each site use
>   DNS to find services such as DCs in their own site, thus preventing
>   the use of services over the WAN link.
>
> Exchange Server 2010 uses Active Directory sites for routing messages
>   between sites. Using the same example of the Exchange Server 2010 Hub
>   Transport Server in Germany and Exchange Server 2010 Hub Transport
>   Server in Bulguria, the IP Site Links in Active Directory would route
>   messages from Germany to Bulguria.
>
> Transport and Routing:-With Exchange Server 2010, you can implement
>   cross-premises message routing. In a mixed hosting environment,
>   Exchange Server 2010 can route messages from the datacenter to the
>   on-premises environment with full transparency. To create a highly
>   available and reliable routing model Active directory helps with the
>   formulation with exchange server.
>
> Unified Messaging:-The Exchange Server 2010 Unified Messaging Server
>   Role can integrate a telephone system like a private automatic branch
>   exchange, or PABX, with the Exchange Server messaging environment.
>   This lets you offer Outlook Voice Access.

Thus beacuse of this reason Both will work well together.